# Probability of drawing multiple cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability, card-games

Suppose we have a deck of `144` cards: `36` kinds of card(`A-Z,0-9`) and each kind has exactly four identical cards, so `36x4=144`.

Now six cards are randomly dealt, without replacement; three are dealt face-up and another three face-down. What's the probability that there is exactly one shared category between face-up cards and face-down cards?

---

Example1: the configuration `U: AAA, D: ABB` satisfies the criterion because there is exactly one shared category(in this case it is `A`) between face-up cards and face-down cards

Example2: the configuration `U: 012, D: AD0` satisfies the criterion because there is exactly one shared category `0`

Example3: the configuration `U: 002, D: A00` satisfies the criterion because there is exactly one shared category `0`.

Example4: the configuration `U: ARZ, D: ARK` does NOT satisfy the criterion because there are two shared categories `A, R` instead of one

Example5: the configuration `U: AAA, D: 999` does NOT satisfy the criterion because `there is zero shared category instead of one

---

EDIT: added that the cards are dealt without replacement and added the tag `conditional-probability`, because the solution to the problem will probably involve it

Comment: How have you tried to solve the problem?  I think you’ll need to break the analysis into three cases.

Comment: I broke down the problem into a conditional probability in the simpler case where only 4 cards are dealt. But I am not sure how to do it correctly in the 6-card case, which is why I am asking for better answer here. Maybe there are more elegant ways to do this

Comment: What about AAA vs AAB?  Does it fail because there are two matched A's?  Or does it succeed because there's only one type matched between the two?

Comment: @Brian Tung, the common types between `AAA` and `AAB` is `A`, so it is considered a success. Note that `AAA` and `AAB` won't happen because there are only 4 `A`'s in the deck

Comment: @mathguy: Oops, sorry, yeah, that should have been AAB vs AAC or something like that.

Comment: @Brian Tung thanks for pointing it out. I already added it as an new example

Comment: I really don't see an elegant solution.  I'd use brute force to solve the problem.  Determine the number of total configurations to get your denominator.  To determine the numerator, break the the face-up cards into three possibilities -- three of a kind, a pair, and three different cards.  Determine how many times each of those can happen.  For each of those, determine how many combinations of face-down cards are "good."

Comment: @RobertShore That's what I did a few hours back, but not sure if it was the only way to do it. That said, I am still waiting for other solutions though, because this way I can at least verify if my answer is correct or not.